# Redireccionar de un JSP a otro JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy intentando de redirrecionar de un JSP a otro JSP, pero no lo he logrado
Tengo lo siguiente de boostrap en el que cuando se presiona el boton este se redirige al controlador pero no hace nada no carga el otro JSP, me pueden ayudar por favor.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="Controlador?accion=Producto">Home</a>
                        
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav
```

En el controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
        String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
    switch (accion) {
        
        
        case "Producto":
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Producto.jsp").forward(request, response);
            break;
        
        default:
            throw new AssertionError();
```